# Calendar Null Object

Tags: java, calendar

```
public class Test {

    //required fields
    private String str1;
    private String str2;

    //optional
    private Calendar cal;

    public Test(String a, String b){
        str1 = a;
        str2 = b;
    }

    //getter for str1 and str2

    public void setCal(Calendar cal){
        this.cal = cal;
    }

    public Calendar getCal() {
        return cal;
    }
}
```

I have a class like this where the calendar object is optional. If setCal() is not called and some one calls the getCal() method, is there any option rather than returning null. If a null is returned then I have to do null checks every where. Is there any class that extends calendar without doing anything like Null Object Pattern.

Whats the best option over here when getCal() is called?

Comment: If it's truly an optional field, why do you have places all over your code trying to pull the value out?  Just encapsulate the behavior into the owning class with a decent default when the calendar isn't set, and get rid of `getCal()`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271526/avoiding-null-statements-in-java

Answer (score 0):

If `setCal` is not called and so if `cal` is not set, why do you want to send other thing than `null` ?
`null` is the best thing to return in this case. Null is also a value, which give an indication to the developper.
And, because developpers don't know that your `getCal` can't return null, they will check for null even if you never return null (I assume that for getter and setter, developpers don't read javadoc).

Maybe you can send a new instance of default Calendar. But default value is the current date, so I don't think it's a good idea since it does not represent the fact that the Calendar has not been set.

Or you can throw an exception... but do not abuse of Exception. Exception are designed to defined error or bad behavior, not to simplify functionnal checks.
However, to protect the `setCal` method of null value, here you can throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if user set null value.

Answer (score 0):

would something like this fix your problem ?

```
public Calendar getCal() {
    if (cal != null)
        return cal;
    return Calendar.getInstance(); // to be returned when cal is null
}
```

Comment: It returns default value, so the current Calendar. Don't think it's a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

Returning null and null checks are best bet here, other wise, what you may do is

Initialize the Calendar to today, if that fits your scenario.

or

Throw an exception and ask to set the Calendar.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a default value to the property:

```
private Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
```

Comment: And you will have a Calendar with the current date, so, it does not represent the fact that no Calendar has been set.

Answer (score 0):

If you are against doing checks for null all over your code, you could implement something like this:

```
    public boolean hasCal(){
        if(this.cal == null){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

This would make your code more readable, but you would still have to have `getCal()` return something even if the `Test` object does not have one, and returning `null` seems to be the best option in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The context of your code is not clear, returning null can be advantageous depending on the context. But in general, when you're trying to say "I have no information to give back", then returning null clearly shows it. Additionally it makes it easier for others to observe that.

> is there any option rather than returning null.

In fact, there are many other ways; it depends on the context. An alternative example is the '[Option Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_type)'. Which its idea relies on encapsulating an optional value; either None or the original data. This way you could return a meaningful value (which is heavily used in Haskell, and to some extent Scala). Although, it should be done with care as returning an encapsulation that indicates 'empty' may not be noticed unless carefully documented and agreed with as a convention (with your team for instance).